# "Relation does not exist" Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have this error:

```
---------------------------
pgAdmin III
---------------------------
An error has occurred:

ERROR:  relation "vettura_tariffa" does not exist
LINE 2:     from vettura_tariffa
                 ^
QUERY:  SELECT (    select valore 
                from vettura_tariffa
                where new.targa=vettura.targa)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "progettoBD".costout() line 14 at assignment
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

the code is the following

```
create or replace function costout()
returns trigger AS
$$ 
DECLARE 
giorno integer;
gg1 integer;
gg2 integer;
tariffa numeric(2,0) ;
costo integer;
BEGIN
        gg1=extract (days from new.dataconsegna);
        gg2=extract (days from new.dataritiro);
        giorno=gg1-gg2;


        tariffa=(   select valore 
                from vettura join tariffa on vettura.tipotariffa=tariffa.tipo
                where new.targa=vettura.targa); 
     costo=tariffa * giorni;
     new.costoutilizzo=costo;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and this one is the trigger's code

```
create trigger costo_utilizzo
after insert on utilizzo
for each row 
execute procedure costout();
```

It seems like it doesn't find the table vettura, it's the same with other tables, and if I try a simply "select * from vettura" it works fine.
I tried swapping the from with a view but the problem persists.
This error appears after the insert on "utilizzo".
Sorry for my bad english, thank you in advance.

Comment: I see both `vettura` and `vettura_tariffa` ??

Comment: `search_path` issues?

Comment: That query didnt generate that error. On the query you call `vettura` but the error is cause by `vettura_tariffa`. Either you are looking the wrong query, or you have another trigger

Comment: the errror wasn't right, it should be "relation "vettura" does not exist", sorry

Answer (score 1):

Solution for JAVA problem.

We need to engage in double quotes and bars so that the command is accepted by postgresql.

`sql = "INSERT INTO \"SCHEMA\".\"TABLE\"() values(?,?,?)`

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Atz34,

The error that is generated indicates that you are calling a function that makes a reference to `vettura_tariffa` while the code you post refers to `vettura JOIN tariffa`. Probably a simple mistake somewhere in your code. However, you have a few more issues with your trigger and trigger function.

First of all, you should call a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger when you modify any fields of `NEW`; on an `AFTER INSERT` trigger the changes will not be saved in the table (you can only do side effects like auditing or making changes to other tables).

Second, `extract(date from ...)` gives problems between months. Assuming your `datacosegna` and `dataritiro` are `date` columns, you can simply subtract them and add 1: `NEW.dataritiro - NEW.dataconsegna + 1` (so same-day returns are not gratis).

Third, always `RETURN NEW` from an insert trigger.

You can then fold all statements into:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costout() RETURNS trigger AS $$ 
BEGIN
  SELECT valore * (NEW.dataritiro - NEW.dataconsegna + 1) INTO NEW.costoutilizzo
  FROM vettura
  JOIN tariffa ON vettura.tipotariffa = tariffa.tipo
  WHERE NEW.targa = vettura.targa;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but even with your advices it doesn't work, and pasting the code i forgot che "return new"

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not enough information to help you. What is the error exactly? (Look in the postgresql log file for more details.) Edit your question to show table definitions.